# Searching controls dynamically by adding search properties in code

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to identify controls at runtime by adding some search properties in my code as and when required. Using Coded UI in Visual Studio 2012.

Please refer to the screenshot below. My test scenario is:

1) Click on a particular tab (the 2<sup>nd</sup> tab selected in the screenshot)

The Tab list is fixed so I can create one control in My UIMap for each tab.

2) Inside every Tab, there is a tabular structure with some data. The Table headings are fixed but the number of rows and the data inside the rows is dynamic.

3) Check the checkBox for the required tag

4) Select Type for required tag

[image: UI for the desktop App(Wpf)]

I have created my UIMap as:

[image: UIMap in CodedUI]

Added following code:

```
UIEquipmentTagText.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WpfText.PropertyNames.Name, "1302"));// say I want second row
To fetch the respective checkbox control, I am using:
UITestControl UIEquipmentTagCell = UIEquipmentTagText.GetParent();//get the cell of Tag name
UITestControl UIEquipmentTagRow = UIEquipmentTagCell.GetParent();//get the row
UITestControl UIEquipmentCheckBoxCell = UIEquipmentTagRow.GetChildren()[0];//get the first cell i.e the checkbox cell
UITestControl UIEquipmentCheckBox = UIEquipmentCheckBoxCell.GetChildren()[0]; // get the checkbox control
```

But this is not working for me. I guess the UIRow control is referring to first row only (though I haven’t specified to look for 1<sup>st</sup> row)

I do not want to include row number in my search criteria for Row.

Is there any workaround to get all the controls I want based on the Tag Text only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured out a solution finally..get all rows and iterate to find the matching row

```
UITestControlCollection allRows = row.FindMatchingControls(); 


            foreach (UITestControl x in allRows)
            {
                UITestControl Tag = x.GetChildren()[1].GetChildren()[0];//row->tag cell->tag text

                if (Tag.GetProperty("Name").Equals("1302"))//say I want to select row having 1302 tag 
                {
                    UITestControl checkBox = Tag.GetParent().GetParent().GetChildren()[0].GetChildren()[0];//TagText->TagCell->Row->CheckBoxCell->Checkbox

                    Mouse.Click(checkBox);
                }

            }
```